# Finding $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{|x|^{1/2} \cos(\pi^{1/x^2})}{2 + (x^2 + 3)^{1/2}} $

Tags: calculus, limits

I was practicing limit and I came across this question:

> $$
> \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{|x|^{1/2} \cos(\pi^{1/x^2})}{2 + (x^2 + 3)^{1/2}} 
> $$

I reasoned the absolute value of $x$ goes to zero, and the denominator goes to $2 + (3)^{1/2}$ by direct substitution. But I couldn't figure our the '$\cos$' part. I first changed the variable to $y= 1/(x^2)$ and so the limit as $y$ approaches infinity of $\cos(\pi^y )$. And $\cos$ of infinity doesn't exist since it doesn't converge to a value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. Note that since $-1\leq\cos(t)\leq 1$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, it follows that
$$-\frac{|x|^{1/2} }{2 + (x^2 + 3)^{1/2}}\leq \frac{|x|^{1/2} \cos(\pi^{1/x^2})}{2 + (x^2 + 3)^{1/2}}\leq  \frac{|x|^{1/2} }{2 + (x^2 + 3)^{1/2}}.$$
Now try again with your approach and recall the [Squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem#Statement).

Answer (score 1):

$|\cos \theta | \leq 1$ for all $\theta$ so the limit is $0$.